# I need advice on how to compact this dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Below is my dataframe, I believe I need to use groupby or pivot but haven't gotten anything to work correctly.

```
       LOGIN  MANAGER     7     8     9    10    11    UNITS  HOURS    UPH
0      joeblow  MSmith    1                             21     1      47.01
1      joeblow  MSmith        0.25                      18     0.25   75.83
2      joeblow  MSmith                1                 12     1      87.05
3      joeblow  MSmith                    0.26          13     0.26   206.9
4      joeblow  MSmith                          0.43    23     0.43   53.18
```

My expected output would look like below, where the UNITS and HOURS are summed and UPH is averaged and the other columns groupby:

```
        LOGIN  MANAGER     7     8     9    10    11    UNITS HOURS    UPH
0      joeblow  MSmith     1    0.25   1   0.26  0.43    66    2.94   93.994
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create your columns `dict` with functions

```
d={'7':'first','8':'first','9':'first','10':'first','11':'first','UNITS':'sum','HOURS':'sum','UPH':'mean'}
```

Then do with `agg`

```
yourdf=df.groupby(['LOGIN','MANAGER']).agg(d)
```

Comment: I'm getting: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str.

Comment: @user3249641 check your columns , maybe it is '7' not 7

Comment: @user3249641 it is better convert all you columns back to numeric (in your case float), then run my code , it should work :-) also , there is a typo in my dict should be UNITS not UNITs

Comment: Yep that was it my df was not converted back to numeric first. Thanks again!